# How should I load non editable text to a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a problem:

I want to 1) load any amount of text to a View and While it's displayed the text has to be non editable. The View should show a scrollbar only when there is a LOT of text. I also want to be able to make highlight any pa_*r*_ticular letter in the text,by either making the letter bold or colorized. Is This at all possible?

Comment: Many things are possible, [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried use a UIScrollView and a UITextView. Both with disappointing results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, you can use UIWebView or a tact which I described you below:

Just add the UITextView in your view and set its border none or whatever you find good, and mark his property non-editable and height whatever you think.So, what's happen that text view is non-editable and also, when text length is enough to that of it's height, it's own scroll.

For non-editable, either you can do programmatically or using IB. In IB just go to check 'Behavior' option in View part of Right Hand Side of XCode, while for programmatically approach:

```
    UITextView* myRequiredTextView = [UITextView new];
    myRequiredTextView.editable = NO;//Don't forget to apply values to other properties like setFrame, etc.
 [self.myView addSubView:myRequiredTextView];
```

And, for highlighting purpose, you can use NSAttributedString.

If you go for webView option, then it's required HTML, so you need a HTML designer for that purpose.

In any concern, just let me know:)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I will for sure keep asking you.

Comment: Sure, also since you don't required editing, so you don't needed to set delegate.:)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use a UIWebView and do your highlighting using HTML.

Comment: thanks. I will make a try... with UiWebView.

Answer (score 1):

if you use UIWebView it use html code,to avoid that problem use [nsattributedstring](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in [CATextLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks a LOT, for your "heads up" call. I will for sure check it up.